# How to gently kill Firefox process on Linux/OS X

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, firefox

I'm doing some automation with Firefox and although I can open Firefox window from shell, I'm not able to terminate it properly. If I `kill` Firefox process with `kill -3` or `kill -2` command the next time I open a new Firefox window it asks me if I want to run in safe-mode. I understand that calling `kill -9` could confuse Firefox so it would try to run in safe-mode but `-3` should be fine.

Do you have any idea how to gently tell Firefox to close properly?

Comment: You should just be able to use: kill pid. The default signal is SIGTERM, which most processes should handle correctly

Comment: I know, but it doesn't work with Firefox. It thinks it crashed.

Comment: Then `firefox` just isn't able to handle `SIGTERM` correctly.

Comment: Some other signals to try : `kill -30` on Mac OSX (`SIGUSR1`) or `kill -10` and `kill -12` (`SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2`) in Linux. Firefox might respond better to them.

Comment: With the pid it should work if you use kill -KILL <pid>

Comment: @Merlin069: I said *gently* :).

Answer (score 17):

You can use `pkill` with the process name:

```
pkill -f firefox
```

Comment: I did try `pkill`. It doesn't show that safe-mode dialogue window but it still thinks that all previously opened tabs crashed.

Comment: See this answer: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/752748 It says `it looks like firefox shuts down cleanly on SIGTERM, so if you just `pkill firefox`, that should do it.

if multiple instances are running and you only want to shut down one instance, you can use something like `pgrep -f [PROFILE] | xargs kill`.`

Comment: Yes, it looks like it terminates properly but it doesn't. Maybe this has changed in more recent versions of Firefox. That thread is from 2010. Maybe it's some OS X specific problem.

Comment: Hmm it could be. I have OSX, let me try some commands myself.

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
wmctrl -c "Mozilla Firefox"
```

?

Is it what you want?

NOTEs:

1. This command may need to be fired in same DISPLAY & probably same virtual desktop, on which your firefox is running.
2. Only first matching window will be closed. You may need to loop this command.

Comment: I don't have any `wmctrl` on OSX

Comment: ok... this package is for linux flavors. but there may be some alternate tool for similar purpose for OSX. Apparently, [it does not compile as-is for OSX](http://superuser.com/questions/496633/trouble-installing-wmctrl).

Comment: `wmctrl` is for X Windows. While X Windows is available for Mac OS X, the primary GUI is not based on it.

Comment: This is the only method that will close Firefox properly under Ubuntu. I say Firefox because it's easy to see its result when it's not closed properly : the restore page.

Answer (score 3):

In Mac OS X, you could use AppleScript to close it (adjust the application name as necessary; I don't have FireFox installed to test):

```
$ osascript -e 'tell application "FireFox"
quit
end tell'
```

This should trigger the same event that the Quit menu command triggers, so FireFox should shut down cleanly.

Obviously, this won't work in Linux.

Comment: Nice, this works as expected. Firefox closes and reopenes fine. I was hoping for some cross-platform solution but if there was no other way, I'll use this.

Comment: See my comment to your question; they're wild guesses, so I didn't add them to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

## A bit more gentle

As @skybert indicated in the comment, you can

> set `browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash` to `false`.

in `about:config`, which

> will rid you of the "Ups, something went wrong ..." message.

To get rid of the *safe-mode* message, you can [set the config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21294259/1587329)

> `toolkit.startup.max_resumed_crashes` to `-1`

or (just set) the environment variable [`MOZ_DISABLE_AUTO_SAFE_MODE`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=745154).

## Less gentle

In lack of a better solution, you can remove `sessionstore.js` from the profile folder after the `killall`.

This is no more "gentle" than your solution, but it fixes the "Safe Mode" message:

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/817752

Comment: There is a more gentle solution, you can enter the `about:config` in Firefox and set `browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash` to `false`.

This will rid you of the "Ups, something went wrong ..." message.

Comment: @skybert: Thanks, the comment has been merged.

Answer (score 2):

You can first get the Pid of firefox with

```
pgrep firefox
```

and after use kill to stop firefox kill [pid]

```
kill `pgrep firefox`
```

Comment: Which is the same as `pkill` except that your solution won't handle multiple running firefox processes correctly.

Comment: `pgrep` is not available in OS X.

Comment: I think it is. Or maybe I installed it via mac ports, I don't remember.

Comment: Probably mac ports or some other 3rd-party mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox in OSX:

```
killall 'firefox'
```

Answer (score 0):

First Run  xkill command after that click on window which one you want close

```
    xkill
```

Answer (score 0):

You can close the FF by kill and PID

#!/bin/bash

firefox & PID=$! # Start Firefox and get PID for later

## Running the FF some time

kill -15 $PID # Soft Kill of FF