# Firefox: Disable automatic safe mode after crash

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to prevent firefox showing the safe mode dialog after the crash?
[image]

It blocks the automatic selenium tests.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have no idea how you got this and what your testing flow is. So I can't reproduce and test the solution. But Firefox [Safe Mode](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Safe_mode) can be disabled by setting the key `toolkit.startup.max_resumed_crashes` in `about:config` to `-1`.

Here's how to start Firefox with that preference set in C# binding:

```c#
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("toolkit.startup.max_resumed_crashes", "-1");

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Firefox 23, you can also use the environment variable [MOZ_DISABLE_AUTO_SAFE_MODE](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=745154) to disable this dialog and the automatic safe mode.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked fine until recently. Can you reproduce this?

Comment: At least with Firefox Portable, this seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the configuration options in `about:config`, there are options for safebrowsing which might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @mmm worked until the recent Tor Browser Bundle (which uses Firefox).

If you need an alternative, you can always delete the line

```
user_pref("toolkit.startup.recent_crashes", 4);
```

from `prefs.js`, for example like

```
sed -i '/toolkit\.startup\.recent_crashes/d' /path/to/prefs.js
```

or call this as

```
os.system("sed -i '/toolkit\.startup\.recent_crashes/d' " +
           os.path.join('/path/to' + 'prefs.js"))
```