# Why Selenium starts Firefox in safe mode sometimes (without user pressing Shift)?

Tags: firefox, selenium

I am using Firefox Selenium Web Driver to run automatic tests on a dedicated testing machine, so there is nobody pressing Shift there that would cause Firefox to start in the safe mode. But still several times a day Firefox starts with this safe mode dialog:

[image: safe mode dialog]

Any idea what could be causing this behavior?

Multiple tests are running at the same time, so there are several Firefox instances, can they maybe influence each other somehow?

I have disabled automatic safe mode after Firefox crashes as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287677/firefox-disable-automatic-safe-mode-after-crash), but without success.

Comment: Are you using a predefined profile?  My guess is that the profile has safe mode enabled.

Comment: Nope, no profile is specified. Web Driver is creating anonymous profile for every test, I think this is a default behavior. Btw the same test is working most of the time, just once in a while it fails because the firefox is started in safe mode. I think it would be failing always if safe mode was enabled in the profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that some of my tests are running external AutoIt script that is "pressing" a Shift key to enter upper case letters. If another test is starting its Firefox at the same moment, Firefox detects the Shift key and displays the Safe Mode dialog.

[osdHotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265274/292628) simple utility that displays and logs pressed keys helped me to find out what is going on.