# How to start Firefox without safe mode via Selenium.WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have call new instance firefox browser by Selenium webdriver in Java

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

When i compiled, firefox starts safe mode. How can i disable safe mode. Because i want to use extensions that doesn't seem safe mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need start Firefox without safe mode, you only need load all wanted extensions.

> 1. Loads the extension inside a File variable,
> 2. Add this extension in a FirefoxProfile variable using the method `addExtension(File)`,
> 3. Set the version of the extension in preferences,
> 4. Start FirefoxDriver with the FirefoxProfile.

Example:

```
File file = new File("path_to_firebug-2.0.17.xpi");
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "2.0.17"); 

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about it but may be [this is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287677/firefox-disable-automatic-safe-mode-after-crash) of your problem. You can disable it by setting preference as `toolkit.startup.max_resumed_crashes` to `-1` to Initialize FirefoxDriver with FirefoxProfile as below :-

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("toolkit.startup.max_resumed_crashes", "-1");

 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```